# What's the difference between belongs_to and has_one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What is the difference between a `belongs_to` and a `has_one`?

Reading the Ruby on Rails guide hasn't helped me.

Answer (score 304, accepted):

They essentially do the same thing, the only difference is what side of the relationship you are on. If a `User` has a `Profile`, then in the `User` class you'd have `has_one :profile` and in the `Profile` class you'd have `belongs_to :user`. To determine who "has" the other object, look at where the foreign key is. We can say that a `User` "has" a `Profile` because the `profiles` table has a `user_id` column. If there was a column called `profile_id` on the `users` table, however, we would say that a `Profile` has a `User`, and the belongs_to/has_one locations would be swapped.

[here](http://duanesbrain.blogspot.com/2006/05/ruby-on-rails-hasone-versus-belongsto.html) is a more detailed explanation.

Comment: ok makes sense, has_a is property, while a belongs is more of a relation.

Comment: So to say it really short:
`Product belongs_to Shop` means `products` table has `shop_id` column

Comment: @ryeguy, what about if this is a self join relationship?

Comment: As far as I understand:  Also remember that Rails will try to find _id column in the database in table of class where you write belongs_to. For example if Question belongs_to :answer Rails will try to find column answer_id in Question table. Or if you write belongs_to :cool_answer Rails will try to find column cool_answer_id. So rails just picks the name from belongs_to and tries to add _id. If there's no such column, Rails will raise an exception or something like this.

Comment: An easy way to remember which is which is that `has_one` puts the foreign key in the same place as `has_many` _(but only expecting a single instance association)_.

Comment: Thanks @karmakaze that's probably the most coherent point I've heard made about this

Answer (score 88):

It's about where the foreign key sits.

```
class Foo < AR:Base
end
```

- If foo `belongs_to :bar`, then the foos table has a `bar_id` column
- If foo `has_one :bar`, then the bars table has a `foo_id` column

On the conceptual level, if your `class A` has a `has_one` relationship with `class B` then `class A` is the parent of `class B` hence your `class B` will have a `belongs_to` relationship with `class A` since it is the child of `class A`.

Both express a 1-1 relationship. The difference is mostly where to place the foreign key, which goes on the table for the class declaring the `belongs_to` relationship.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # I reference an account.
  belongs_to :account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  # One user references me.
  has_one :user
end
```

The tables for these classes could look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  account_id int(11) default NULL,
  name varchar default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)

CREATE TABLE accounts (
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)
```

Comment: That is pretty much the same the accepted answer from two years ago already states.

Comment: This is pretty much a better answer.

Comment: The use of `Account` and `User` in this example is unfortunate since it is often the case that an Account can have many users.

Comment: @karmakaze That works because you can simply change the association to has_many instead of has_one without any other changes.

Answer (score 10):

`has_one` and `belongs_to` generally are same in a sense that they point to the other related model. `belongs_to` make sure that this model has the `foreign_key` defined.
      `has_one` makes sure that the other model `has_foreign` key defined.

To be more specific, there are two sides of `relationship`, one is the `Owner` and other is `Belongings`. If only `has_one` is defined we can get its `Belongings` but cannot get the `Owner` from the `belongings`. To trace the `Owner` we need to define the `belongs_to` as well in the belonging model.

Answer (score 4):

One additional thing that I want to add is, suppose we have the following models association.

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end
```

If we only write the above association, then we can get all books of a particular author with

```
@books = @author.books
```

but, for a particular book, we can't get the corresponding author with

```
@author = @book.author
```

To make the above code work we need to add an association to the `Book` model as well, like this

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end
```

This will add method 'author' to the `Book` model. For mode details see [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Answer (score 1):

`has_one`

- This method should only be used if the `other class` contains the `foreign key`.

`belongs_to`

- This method should only be used if the `current class` contains the `foreign key`.

Answer (score 1):

As many (all?) other answers have pointed out, it's all about where the foreign key is stored.

But that's not necessarily very memorable, so this way of thinking about it may help you:

- if you want to keep track of something you own, you might write your name on your possession (such as having your Air Pods or iPhone engraved with your name)
- but you never, on the other hand, have the name of your iPhone or Air Pods tattooed on your body.

Therefore the foreign key (a reference to the owner) always goes on the thing (record) that is owned, not a record of the possession on the owner.

Answer (score 0):

From a simplicity standpoint, `belongs_to` is better than `has_one` because in  `has_one`, you would have to add the following constraints to the model and table that has the foreign key to enforce the `has_one` relationship:

- `validates :foreign_key, presence: true, uniqueness: true`
- add a database unique index on the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most reliable memory tool I use to remember the direction of has_many/one and belongs_to:

You write your name on the stuff that belongs to you. Your notebook or driver's license has *your* name written on it. You might have many notebooks and one driver's license...but all of them belong to only one person.

A child record that belongs to a parent/owning record always has the name of the owning record written on it. That is, `child.owner_id` is written on the child record, which belongs to the parent record.

The parent record has nothing written on it to identify the child records that has_many of. Just like you don't tattoo book titles or license numbers on your body.