# Followers model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app Users can follow each other. I have two tables: `users` and `followers`.

```
users

id
name

followers

id
user_id
follower_id
```

And two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :followers
  belongs_to :follower

end

class Follower < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

end
```

What I want to do is list the followers for a user. e.g.

```
<ul>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <li><%= user.name %></li>
      <ul>
        <% user.followers.each do |follower| %>
            <li><%= follower.name %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

However it doesn't look to be seeing the association...

---

After updating my model as per Deep's suggestions I got it working... however I'm unable to query followers and following users.

e.g.

I have two methods in my UsersController:

```
def user_followers
  @user = User.where(id: params[:id]).first
  @followers = @user.get_followers
end

def user_following
  @user = User.where(id: params[:id]).first
  @following = @user.get_following
end
```

and then in my User model I have:

```
def get_followers
  Follower.where(follower_id: self.id)
end

def get_following
  Follower.where(user_id: self.id)
end
```

Which should be returning the followers for the user or who the user is following. The views look like so:

```
<% @followers.each do |follower| %>
    <%= follower.user.name %>
<% end %>

<% @following.each do |following| %>
    <%= following.user.name %>
<% end %>
```

However it only returns the name of the user I'm supposed to be viewing.

The Follower model now looks like:

```
class Follower < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'follower_id', class_name: 'User'

end
```

Comment: this sound more like a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation. And to your problem: any error message?

Comment: The error is that it can't find the `name` because it doesn't see `follower` as a user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `follower.name` will not work because your `follower` model has no attribute named `name`. Also the association you have given is `belongs_to :user` which will fetch the `user` who has been followed. You need another association in the `Follower` model like:

```
belongs_to :following_user, foreign_key: 'follower_id', class_name: 'User'
```

And then in your view what you can do is:

```
<%= follower.following_user.name %>
```

This will fetch the user who has followed and from that object it will fetch the name attribute.

**Update:**

Don't remove the existing association you have. Means your model should look like:

```
belongs_to :user    
belongs_to :following_user, foreign_key: 'follower_id', class_name: 'User'
```

Now as discussed in comments `user_id` will consist of the `user` who is being followed and `follower_id` will consist of the `user` who is following.

To fetch the `followers` of a user you have the association which will find the `followers`. Just like `user.followers`. And to fetch the name:

```
<% user.followers.each do |follower| %>
   <li><%= follower.following_user.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

To find the followed users:

```
def followed_users
  Follower.where(follower_id: id)
end
```

And to fetch the name:

```
<% user.followed_users.each do |follower| %>
   <li><%= follower.user.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Gives me the error: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.follower_id: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."follower_id" = ? LIMIT 1`

Comment: Can you try including `primary_key: 'id'` in the association?

Comment: Aah.. just change the `has_one` to `belongs_to` and try please

Comment: That was a mistake of `foreign_key`. You can read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808926/whats-the-difference-between-belongs-to-and-has-one

Comment: I've found another association issue, check my updated OP to see what I mean.

Comment: I didn't understand your issue. What you need is the list of `followers` that is in `@followers` (it consist of the object of `Follower` model). Now you are looping it and fetching the `name` so it will get you the `name` only. What else do you want?

Comment: The `name` is of the user I'm viewing. So if user 1 is 'Cameron' and has 4 users following him, I will see the name 'Cameron' 4 times. Where as what I want to see is the 4 names of the users following.

Comment: If I put it another way... `def get_followers
    Follower.where(follower_id: self.id)
    self.followers
  end` this works. But what is wrong with my query?

Comment: It completely depends on how you have saved the `user_id` and `follower_id`. It seems that when saving the follower you have saved the user_id of user who is following in `user_id` and to whom he is following in `follower_id`.

Comment: That's correct. But I want to be able to query to see a list of users following a user and a list of users being followed by a user.

Comment: That doesn't look to be working at the moment, as `.followers` looks to return all users from the db that match the `user_id` (regardless of follower or following)

Comment: I think you need to save this in the opposite way and it will work fine. `user_id` will consist of the user who is being followed and `follower_id` will consist of the user who if following.

Comment: Okay doing that now. But how I get a list of followers (users following this user) for a particular user, and also a list of following (users that this user is following) for a user. Could you show an example of how to get these two lists? Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer. Check it.