# How can I introduce a has_one_belongs_to_one association in Rails model?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My Rails application has users and tasks created by users. Users can also create a task and assign another user to it. I am not quite sure how to build associations here.

I know since a task is created by a user, I can have an association as below,

```
class User
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

```
class Task
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I also want to add an association for creator in the `Task` model but I am not sure how to do it since a creator will also be an instance of the `User` class and I already have a `belongs_to` association with `User`

I tried to add an association for creator in `Task` model in the following way but it didn't work.

```
has_one :user, foreign_key: :creator_id, class_name: "User"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've already defined the `belongs_to :user` method, the method `@task.user` is already taken by that association. You can't use the same name for a different method, so you'll have to use a different name for that association.

The association name doesn't have to be the same as the model. You can name the creator association something else, like "creator":

```rb
has_one :creator, foreign_key: 'creator_id', class_name: "User"
```

Since the task has a foreign key for the creator, you should be able to use belongs_to for both associations:

```rb
class Task
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :creator, foreign_key: 'creator_id', class_name: 'User'
end
```

Here's a discussion about the difference between `has_one` and `belongs_to`: [What's the difference between belongs_to and has_one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808926/whats-the-difference-between-belongs-to-and-has-one)

Either way way you can do:

```rb
@task.user    # the User who is assigned the task
@task.creator # the User who created the task
```